# ClientException: Client Error giving '401 Unauthorized' error in GuzzleHttp using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to use **GuzzelHttp** for send HTTP request, but when I run it I get the error:

> Client error: `POST http://localhost:8100/api/customers?company_id=9` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

Below is the code I wrote:

```
Route::get('/testguzzel', function() {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
    $res = $client->request('POST', 
        'http://localhost:8100/api/customers?company_id=9',
        ['auth' => ['username', 'password'],
        'headers' => ['Accept'=> 'application/vnd.twareeq.v1+json']]);

    return $res->getBody()->getContents();
});
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to use basic or digest authentication? Have you tried specifying the right one [as described in the docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#auth)?

Comment: i used basic laravel authentication